# Getting boost::function from boost::lambda::bind of new_ptr with parameters

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost-bind, boost-function

I am trying to obtains a boost::function to a new_ptr (with parameters) which can be stored in a hash table for later use. A kind of registrar of ids to constructors for modules to use. Below is the simplified problem :

```
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/construct.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

using namespace boost::lambda;

struct TestObject
{
    TestObject(int p){}
};

void doStuff()
{
    boost::function<TestObject*(int)> tf1 = bind(new_ptr<TestObject>(), _1);
}
```

The binding works by itself, but the syntax for boost::function must be off, because it gives me:

```
error C2664: 'TestObject::TestObject(int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'boost::lambda::lambda_functor<T>' to 'int' BOOST\1.57.0\boost\lambda\construct.hpp 146 1
```

I've done this before with constructors that have no parameters (works great). I can't figure out exactly what's missing, or if I'm trying to do something impossible.

Compiling with boost v1.57.0 and msvc 2012 (v110).

Comment: Can't repro, what files are you including? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Still compiles fine for me as is.

Comment: gcc v5.2.1 compiles this code fine, what compiler did you use and what is exact error?

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Code compiles on [standalone MSVC 2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/11/02/announcing-visual-c-build-tools-2015-standalone-c-tools-for-build-environments/)

You may Upgrade your VS, reconfigure Visual Studio 2012 to MSVC 2015 or encapsulate your functions on a lib/dll compiled from command line.

Comment: Good to know, I'll keep it in mind. Not an immediate possibility for me, unfortunately.